# Unexpected output while executing string methods

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  static char s1[]="Good";
  static char s2[20];
  static char s3[20]="Day";

  int i = strcmp(strcat(s3,strcpy(s2,s1)),strcat(s3,"good"));

  printf("%d\n",i);

  return 0;
}
```

Here the output is 0, which implies that the two strings passed as arguments to `strcmp` are equal.  But for `strcmp` the first argument is `"DaygoodGood"` and second is `"Daygood"`...

Why is this happening?

Comment: @WhozCraig, you're right, but this has nothing to do with the reason he's not getting the result he expected.

Comment: strcat(s3,"good").....right to left associative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are comparing `s3` with `s3`, no matter how you look at it.  You'll always get equal doing that.  Just break it down - changing:

```
    i=strcmp(strcat(s3,strcpy(s2,s1)),strcat(s3,"good"));
```

into:

```
    char *s4 = strcpy(s2,s1);     // s4 == s2 -> "Good"
    char *s5 = strcat(s3,s4);     // s5 == s3 -> "DayGood"
    char *s6 = strcat(s3,"good"); // s6 == s3 -> "DayGoodgood"

    i = strcmp(s5, s6);           // same as strcmp(s3, s3)
```

Now whether it *really* happens this way, or if it's:

```
    char *s4 = strcpy(s2,s1);     // s4 == s4 -> "Good"
    char *s6 = strcat(s3,"good"); // s6 == s3 -> "Daygood"
    char *s5 = strcat(s3,s4);     // s5 == s3 -> "DaygoodGood"

    i = strcmp(s5, s6);           // same as strcmp(s3, s3)
```

Instead, is unspecified by the standard.  Regardless, you're comparing identical strings, whichever order the concatenations happen in.  You're either comparing `"DayGoodgood"` to `"DayGoodgood"` or `"DaygoodGood"` to `"DaygoodGood"`, but you should expect `0` as a result either way.

Comment: +1 the comments after the calls will likely assist the OP in at least seeing that he's not comparing just "identical strings" he's comparing the *same* string to *itself*.

Comment: Thanks - I was trying to come up with a good way to explain that.

Comment: A `printf("%p, %p\n, (void*)s5, (void*)s6);` or some such would probably drive the last nail in the coffin =P

Answer (score 3):

The *result* of `strcat(t, s)` is always equal to `t`.  If you find this confusing, remember that strings in C are character *pointers*, so we are talking about the two pointers being equal, not about the (previous or current) contents of string `t`.

Therefore, the two strings compared are `s3` and `s3`, no matter what `s3` contains at that time.  Of course they are equal.

Answer (score 1):

This is because first `strcat` returns `s3`, just as the second. First invocation appends something to `s3`'s content, second appends more, but both return the same pointer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, thank-you for this question.  It is actually more complicated than one might believe at first glance.

The first concept to understand is that of "side-effects".  That is, when a parameter invokes a function then that function might modify data such that how the parameter is evaluated is modified.

For example, when evaluating `strcmp(A,B)` which parameter is evaluated first, A or B?  If A and B are just variables then it does **NOT** matter.  However, if they are themselves functions, it can matter: `strcmp(A(1), B(2))` it might/maybe make a difference if A(1) is evaluated first or `B(2)`.

Let's look specifically at your code:

```
 strcmp(strcat(s3,strcpy(s2,s1)),strcat(s3,"good"));
```

It can be evaluated internally by the compiler as:

```
 A)
    strcat(s3,strcpy(s2,s1));  //s3 = "DayGood'
    strcat(s3,"good");         //s3 = "DayGoodgood"
    strcmp(s3, s3);
```

or it can be evaluated as:

```
 B)
    strcat(s3,"good");         // s3 = "Daygood"
    strcat(s3,strcpy(s2,s1));  // s3 = "DaygoodGood"
    strcmp(s3, s3);
```

So, s3 has two possible values, depending on how a compiler evaluates parameters, and the difference is evidence of "side-effects".

Finally, to see exactly how your compiler works, then modify your printf statement:

```
  printf("\n%d, %s\n\n", i, s3);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks ...i got it ..but if we consider any one solution as you mentioned(let us consider B) ...the second argument is "Daygood" and first is "DaygoodGood"...so final expression becomes strcmp("DaygoodGood","Daygood")....is it not???...

Comment: @user2712068, no they're both "DaygoodGood".  They're both `s3` so they both are the same string.

Comment: so while comparing just base address of s3 is returned....hence when comparing, s3 is modified to DaygoodGood at its address...is this right????

Comment: @user2712068, no in either case of how the compiler evaluates the parameters, A first B second, or A second B first, s3 is set to a value, and then s3 is compared to s3 which is always true.